# How to change UserName in ASPNETDB.MDF

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I am doing some howmework, and my userName is located in an automatically created Database, called ASPNET.DB

I need to change the value of the field user name, but i dontKnow how to call the primary key if the table(userName).

This is what i did:

```
protected void brukEndringerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string txtInput = navnTextBox.Text;        

        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\ASPNETDB.MDF;Trusted_Connection=True;User Instance=yes");

        String comm = "SELECT * FROM Informasjon";
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comm, conn);
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuild = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
        adapter.Fill(dataset, "Informasjon");

        DataRow dr = dataset.Tables["Informasjon"].Rows[???????];

        dr["UserName"] = txtInput;

        adapter.Update(dataset, "Informasjon");
        conn.Close();

        infoLabel.Text = "Endringer som gjøres!";
    }
```

Some how i need to find the Row with a given userId so the program will know what Row needs to Update. 
I don't know how to get that data, the only thing i can call is

> User.Identity.name;

Any ideas how can i modify that column?

Comment: Is this something you want to do all the time or is it just this time.. because if it's just something you dont want to do automated just click on the world icon with a hammer on top of the solution explorer and edit it manually

Comment: Da i want to do this each time i fill the field. I know i can open the DB and change the values manually, i need to do it from the page.(Its for a homework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be using the asp.net membership provider.  If so, all the info you need is right in the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx

No need to work directly with the database (assuming you are using the membership provider).

Comment: I don't think you can change the UserName other than coding directly against the database. `Property or indexer 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser.UserName' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it this way, try having a hidden field with the previous value of the username.  Now you can add a Where statement to your sql.

Or

You can use MembershipService to get the MembershipUser where the username = User.Identity.name

The ProviderUserKey is the userid.

That should be enough to get you on your way, I don't want to give you to much if it is for homework.

Hope it helps